# php function changing value of oblect, even though passed by value

Tags: php

I ran into this issue and finally tracked it down to `Object` value changed inside a function affects the object outside the function.

```
    function fnc1($data)
{
    foreach($data as $i=>$obj)
        if(!isset($x))$obj->dtObj = date('Y-m-d');
}

for($n=0;$n<5;$n++)
{
    $tmp = new stdclass;
    $tmp->dtObj = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:0$n:s"));
    $data[] = $tmp;
}
fnc1($data);
print_r($data);
```

outputs;

```
 Array (
 [0] => stdClass Object
     (
         [dtObj] => 2019-08-13
     )

 [1] => stdClass Object
     (
         [dtObj] => 2019-08-13
     )

 [2] => stdClass Object
     (
         [dtObj] => 2019-08-13
     )

 [3] => stdClass Object
     (
         [dtObj] => 2019-08-13
     )

 [4] => stdClass Object
     (
         [dtObj] => 2019-08-13
     )
  )
```

Is this normal and how PHP works? If I want to avoid this happening I have to send `serialized` data to a function?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Objects are passed by reference, so yes that's expected. There are at least a couple of ways to avoid this, but it kind of depends what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: You can clone an object `$b = clone $a;` to work with a copy, but then you need to read up on how cloning works if you've got nested objects. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Comment: This section of the manual explains how this works, and yes, it is normal behaviour. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: What exactly is the problem? One thing is that $x is undefined, maybe that contributes to your problem? `if(!isset($x))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in PHP User Contributed Notes;

> When using the "->", you will of course be accessing the same
>   internals as the original variable in the caller function.

The entire comment is a must read:
[There seems to be some confusion here. The distinction between pointers and references is not particularly helpful....](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php#101900)

Then it goes on to illustrate the various scenarios